# Cloudflare for Proxy Server

Tags: proxy, cloudflare, squid

I am a beginner in both Cloudflare and Proxy service, so I want your help in setting up a Proxy Server that uses Cloudflare. What I want to achieve is that user uses my proxy server in his browser settings, that proxy server itself uses Cloudflare.

I installed Squid3 on Debian server, and can use the server IP address as proxy settings in the browser, and all website loads fine. So I setup my Domain with Cloudflare Nameservers and within Cloudflare settings I put A record to my proxy server.

Now when I set that Domain name as the Proxy settings in the browser, only those websites load which are using CloudFlare's nameservers. All other websites show me Cloudflare's Error: 1001 - DNS resolution error.

My question is, is it possible to achieve what I am trying? If it is then what is the problem in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CloudFlare only reverse proxy services meaning for a given domain we'll sit in front of your origin server and proxy all requests using a change to your DNS. Our self-service products don't allow you to proxy connections from a client to the internet in general.

If this is behaviour you're after, it's best to c[ontact CloudFlare's sales team](https://www.cloudflare.com/enterprise-service-request/) so something bespoke can be worked out.

Comment: I did sent the email. Thanks.